# '95 Chrysler Lebaron Shifting

Tags: automatic-transmission, chrysler

I have a 1995 Chrysler Lebaron. 3.0L, V6, Automatic transmission.

It has recently developed an issue where as you accelerate, it seems to get "stuck" in third(maybe?) gear. It will drive with that gear stuck for a few seconds, and then shift up. However, if you leave it stuck in that gear and try to slow down, the car will stall.

I have found that some people  have had this issue where their Lebaron goes into "Limp" mode, and stays that way. It seems like this may be what happens, but it only stays that way for a few seconds, if I'm accelerating.

A possibly related problem that it developed at the same time is with the Tachometer; sometimes it will intermittently not reflect the true RPMs of the vehicle.

I have replaced the Transmission control solenoid; as well as the output speed sensor.

My questions are as follows:
- What could be causing this issue with the shifting?
- I suspect the computer being reset might help with recalibration (if that is causing the issue), but attempts to have the computer reset successfully have failed. Is there a way to reset the computer manually?

Answer (score 2):

Many things can lead to this condition.

For a home mechanic to diagnose, some possibilities include:

- Low ATF level.
- Worn engine/transmission mounts or shift cable can also cause the
  shift mechanism to "downshift" one notch.
- Clogged ATF coolant hose or filter.

Other possibilities are harder to diagnose without specialty instruments, including:

- Sticky valve body.
- Worn clutches.
- If it has a locking converter,
  there are some associated sensor(s) and actuator(s) that could be
  suspect.